# Is it better to reuse the same instance of awt.Graphics than to create copies with Graphics.create()?

Tags: java

I got involved with some folks making a new 2D game engine in Java, and I got curious when I learned they avoided using any variation of Graphics.create in their engine's code.

When asked, they said they feared making copies of Graphics for every graphical component seemed like "(...)quite some amount of overhead."
But they could not provide any proof of the claim. Instead of making use of the clipRect and translation properties of Graphics, they instead provide their own support API for drawing in the right place.

I'm not a part of their team, but I do use their unfinished engine in my own project, so I want to find out.
Looking for an answer myself resulted only in a brick wall. The Graphics class is abstract, and I have so far not found any implementation code. So I can't find the answer.

And so I end up asking here.
What performance/memory cost if any, is there for using the Graphics.create() function?

Comment: That clearly depends on the implementation of the `Graphics` class since it is an abstract method any sub class have to implement.

Comment: That is exactly why I ask. I need to know from someone who understands how awt.Graphics is typically implemented.

Comment: Look for the `java.awt.Graphics2D` which is used in AWT/Swing as the implementation of the `java.awt.Graphics` class.

Comment: Considering that evertime `paintComponent` is entered the `identityHashCode` for the graphics context is different I would suspect that a new one is provided.  This would seem to be different than what I learned about not changing the passed graphics context.

Comment: Generally speaking, all `Graphics#create` does it takes a snapshot of the "properties" of the context.  This allows the implementation to "restore" the properties or state of the parent context when the child context is "disposed".  How this is done is implementation detail and would impossible to answer accurately.  I used to do the same thing (roll my own), but to be honest, I found `create`/`dispose` to be simpler and more reliable.  Personally, it "might" create bottle necks in some circumstances, but you'd have to profile it to be sure

Comment: @WJS Just remember, in Swing, the paint context is shared between ALL the components been painted for a given paint pass, so changing the context could have adverse affects on other components over time - had this issue with a developer who had changed the anti-aliasing state, which would make the entire UI "flick" noticeably when the component was first rendered or the rendering order of the components changed (which then applied anti-aliasing to all the other components, which weren't anti-aliased before) 

Comment: I'd also consider the fact the concept isn't that foreign to other frameworks (snapshotting the context) and the operation is probably done a number of times internally anyway, I would consider not using it an anti-pattern without clear evidence that it's causing issues.  However, is the workflow that the other team has done causing any kind of issues?  It's catch 22.  Does using the provided API cause issues?  Does the supposed "work-around" causing any issues?  I'm all for using the internal API functionality until I have a use-case where rolling my own is better.

Comment: Having said that, you might find that one particular platform (like linux or Mac) might suffer more from using `create`/`dispose` then the others, so a "decision" was made to apply a "common work around" for or platforms to provide a more "consistent" workflow - but that's just guess work

Comment: You bring up something I have been unsure of, Mad. Is the implementation of Graphics in the jre? So it is implemented diffrently on diffrent platforms?

Comment: Yes, Graphics requires native code to work, since it renders images to the display, and so its implementation is completely platform dependent.